# Some doubts related to Multi Installation → Media of one of the site can be used on the others?

Tags: multisite

If I install wordpress through Multi Installation Here →

http://photo.bollywoodhatke.com and

http://www.bollywoodhatke.com

all the media(**Photographs are uploaded**) in http://photo.bollywoodhatke.com/

so can I use the media's(uploaded on http://photo.bollywoodhatke.com) while creating posts on http://www.bollywoodhatke.com
 just like as if the medias are uploaded on the http://www.bollywoodhatke.com

I mean we can use it as **smoothly** as like using the **add media** feature on the **single post** pages of the http://www.bollywoodhatke.com.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can, try the "Network Shared Media" plugin by Joost de Keijzer https://en-au.wordpress.org/plugins/network-shared-media/